# Using Subqueries (Common Table Expression) As Filters

Tags: sql, subquery, common-table-expression

**tl;dr:** My filter conditions are significantly different based on delivery date of today vs yesterday. How can utilize subqueries to simplify my code?

---

I've been teaching myself SQL and am pretty solid on most concepts, with the exception of subqueries. Generally I gather that I can use *WITH ___ AS* before my query to return results that meet the conditions specified in the subquery. I thought I could make it work with more than one subquery but I'm having trouble. It works with one subquery but not with multiple. I know this can be done within a WHERE statement but it would be quite complex. Here is an example of what I'd like to do:

```
WITH todays_results AS(
SELECT
order_id,
status,
message
FROM delivery_statuses
WHERE delivery date = STRLEFT(CAST(now() AS string,10)
AND (status = 'delivered'
OR (status = 'out for delivery' AND message = 'On vehicle for delivery')
OR (status = 'in transit' AND message <>'At sort center')
),

yesterdays_results AS (
SELECT
order_id,
status,
message
FROM delivery_statuses
WHERE delivery date = STRLEFT(CAST(now() - INTERVAL 1 days AS string,10)
AND (status = 'delivered'
OR (status = 'out for delivery' AND message = 'Shipment will be delivered within 1 hour')
OR (status = 'pre transit' AND message <>  'Order processing')
)

SELECT
*

FROM customer_details cd
INNER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM todays_results) tr
ON cd.order_id = tr.order_id
INNER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM yesterdays_results) yr
ON cd.order_id = yr.order_id
```

How can I make this return the results that match the first subquery and below the results the second subquery? I would like to even add a third subquery.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you should use `UNION ALL` in your final query. Have a google and see if that helps. Sample data would clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

Give each **with clause** a number to identify it.
Then you can **union all** the joins, and **order** the results by the common **id** column.

```
-- this code has not been tested.
WITH 
A AS
(
    SELECT 1 ID, OTHER_STUFF FROM SOME_WHERE
),
B AS
(
    SELECT 2 ID, OTHER_STUFF FROM SOME_WHERE_ELSE
)
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT A.ID, C.*
    FROM TABLEX C
    JOIN A
      ON A.KEY = C.KEY

    UNION ALL

    SELECT B.ID, D.*
    FROM TABLEX D
    JOIN B
      ON B.KEY = D.KEY
) 
ORDER BY ID
```